# Java Generics - way around instantiating wildcard type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to build a lib that supports deployment of custom implementations of a specific object.

- Class A is the deployment entry point that the users will tell how they want things to be configured
- Class B will be the object that holds the custom implementation instance
- Class C will be the abstract class that the users can extend to create their own custom implementation
- Class D will be the custom implementation that extends Class C (NOT PART OF THE LIB)

When the user is setting things up with Class A, I want them to be able to do something like this:

```
/* this code will not be part of the lib */
ClassA a = new ClassA()
a.setClassCImpl(ClassD.class)
```

Now when Class B gets instantiated it needs to know to use the custom implementation *Class D*

```
/* this code will be part of the lib */
Class<? extends ClassC> classCImpl;

ClassB() {
    classCImpl = new ??? // this needs to be an instance of Class D
}
```

There will be many instances of Class B. I'd rather not need Class B to hold onto an instance of Class A, but I'm not sure this will be possible without using static stuff in Class A.

Comment: Store the `Class` object passed in `a.setClassCImpl()` and use the `newInstance()` method defined in `Class`. (Or use `getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` for Java 9+.)

Comment: This will require me to change `Class<? extends ClassC> classCImpl;` to `ClassC classCImpl;` What's the difference?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new `Class` object inside the `ClassB()` constructor? Shouldn't you just be passing the `Class` object injected into the configuration (the `ClassA` instance)?

Comment: Why mess around with classes like this? Just injecting a Supplier to supply you an instance of the class. Then the user can instantiate the class however they want and your class B will have a fully functioning instance.

Comment: Having to pass the custom implementation type through `Class B`'s constructor isn't nice. I currently have it set up like @TedHopp's original comment. But like I said I had to switch it from `? extends ClassC` to just `ClassC`. I think this might be the best way to do it. I'm just not sure the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of pattern is a good use case for using annotations. Some frameworks implement this kind of behavior but you can quite easily achieve it.

If you can allow users to extend B annotations are really convenient.

For example declare your annotation like that :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

public @interface MeaningfulName {
    public Class<? extends ClassC> value(); // you can define a default
}
```

Now when your users extend B they can add this annotation

```
@MeaningfulName(ClassD.class)
public class CustomB extends ClassB {
    // whatever your class does
}
```

Then you can extract this at runtime using [getAnnotation()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) and setup some caching maybe to avoid frequent lookups. After obtaining the Class attribute you can get the appropriate instance using your desired strategy (singleton, factory, straight up reflection etc.).

If you just want to stick to a single B class, you can specify various combinations of locations users could use it using `@Target` and [other ElementTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html), although with different ways to extract the annotation.

Comment: This is interesting. I will look into this, thanks! If you could edit your answer though, it is kinda throwing me off because you have it set up so that `ClassB` is the one that will be extended but it is not - `ClassC` is the abstract class. Being able to define a default implementation is perfect because it is not required for my users to provide their own implementation.

Comment: I corrected the class definition using ClassD to mitigate confusion. There's no real benefit to a type annotation honestly if your classes are gonna be final. You're better off with a Supplier<ClassC> or a factory pattern in that case.

Answer (score -1):

ClassA:

```
ClassA {
    static Class<? extends ClassC> impl = ClassD.class
}
```

ClassB:

```
ClassC classCImpl;

ClassB() {
    classCImpl = ClassA.impl.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Please use answers to just post the solution to your problem. If you have any further questions, ask a new Question instead.